# How to Write Test Class for Accounts with or without Opportunities?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I wrote the following test class for my Apex code "LastModifiedOppty", but it didn't work and resulted in code coverage 0%.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  My apologies I have just started the coding portion of my Salesforce knowledge base, so any advice would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

**Here's my test class:**

```
@isTest
private class LastModifiedOpptyTest {

@isTest static void testAccountWithOpp() {       
// Accounts with Opportunities

    Account acct1   = new Account();
    acct1.Name      = 'testAccount1';

    Insert acct1;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name        = 'testOpportunity';
    opp.StageName   = 'Prospecting';
    opp.CloseDate   = Date.today();
    opp.AccountId   = acct1.Id;
    opp.Amount      = 100000;     

    Insert opp; 

        Test.startTest();

            List <Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount from 
                                         Opportunities ORDER BY 
                                         LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
                                         FROM Account WHERE Id = :acct1.Id];

            System.assertEquals(opp.Id, acct1.Last_Opportunity_ID__c);
            System.assertEquals(opp.Amount, acct1.Last_Opportunity_Amount__c);

            LastModifiedOppty.updateLastOpptyIdField();

        Test.stopTest();  

}

@isTest static void testAccountWithoutOpp() {
// Accounts without Opportunities 

    Account acct2 = new Account();
    acct2.Name    = 'testAccount2';

    Insert acct2; 

        Test.startTest();

            List <Account> accountList2 = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount 
                                          from Opportunities ORDER BY 
                                          LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
                                          FROM Account WHERE Id = :acct2.Id];

            System.assertEquals('Without Oppty', acct2.Last_Opportunity_ID__c); 

            LastModifiedOppty.updateLastOpptyIdField();

        Test.stopTest(); 

}

}
```

**Here's my Apex Class "LastModifiedOppty":**

```
public class LastModifiedOppty {

public static void updateLastOpptyIdField() {
  // Retrieve the last modified opportunity's ID for each account.
  Account[] accountList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount from Opportunities ORDER 
                           BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account];


  // to access the opportunity related to individual account and pass the Id value on to the Last_Opportunity_ID__c field.
  // if the account does not have any opportunities, pass the value 'Without Oppty' to the Last_Opportunity_ID__c field.

    for(Account acct : accountList){

        if(acct.Opportunities.size()>0){
        Opportunity relatedOpp              = acct.Opportunities[0];                    
            acct.Last_Opportunity_ID__c     = relatedOpp.Id;
            acct.Last_Opportunity_Amount__c = relatedOpp.Amount;

        } else if(acct.Opportunities.size()==0){
            acct.Last_Opportunity_ID__c     = 'Without Oppty';
        }

        }

      update accountList;

}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your Assert statement might be failing because before running the logic you're trying to assert the values whereas the logic is run after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Test class method to assert the values after the code logic is executed

```
Test.startTest();
   LastModifiedOppty.updateLastOpptyIdField();
Test.stopTest(); 
List <Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount from 
                                         Opportunities ORDER BY 
                                         LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
                                         FROM Account WHERE Id = :acct1.Id];

System.assertEquals(opp.Id, acct1.Last_Opportunity_ID__c);
System.assertEquals(opp.Amount, acct1.Last_Opportunity_Amount__c);
```

Comment: Hi, @RCS,  thanks a lot for pointing that out!  I modified as you suggested but am still getting 0% coverage.  I couldn't figure out what might have been missing...

Comment: Is there any specific error that you're getting can you add the debug logs what exactly you're getting in that

Comment: Hi, @RCS, Thanks for the hint! I checked the debug logs and made two problematic triggers inactive and was able to get 100% coverage! I am now checking why the two triggers are causing problems. Thank you so much for your willingness to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into System.AssertException issues after disabling two problematic triggers. And this is the final test class that got me 100% code coverage:

```
@isTest
private class LastModifiedOpptyTest {

@isTest static void testAccountWithOpp() {       
    // Accounts with Opportunities

    Account acct1   = new Account();
    acct1.Name      = 'testAccount1';

    Insert acct1;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name        = 'testOpportunity';
    opp.StageName   = 'Prospecting';
    opp.CloseDate   = Date.today();
    opp.AccountId   = acct1.Id;
    opp.Amount      = 100000;     

    Insert opp; 

        Test.startTest();           
            LastModifiedOppty.updateLastOpptyIdField();         
        Test.stopTest();  

            List <Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, Last_Opportunity_Amount__c, Last_Opportunity_ID__c, (SELECT Id, Amount from Opportunities ORDER 
                                                      BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id = :acct1.Id];
            for(Account account : accountList){     
            Opportunity relatedOpp = account.Opportunities[0];
            System.assertEquals(relatedOpp.Id, account.Last_Opportunity_ID__c);
            System.assertEquals(relatedOpp.Amount, account.Last_Opportunity_Amount__c);
            }
 }

@isTest static void testAccountWithoutOpp() {
    // Accounts without Opportunities 

    Account acct2 = new Account();
    acct2.Name    = 'testAccount2';

    Insert acct2; 

        Test.startTest();           
            LastModifiedOppty.updateLastOpptyIdField();         
        Test.stopTest(); 

            List <Account> accountList2 = [SELECT Id, Last_Opportunity_ID__c, (SELECT Id, Amount from Opportunities ORDER 
                                                      BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id = :acct2.Id];
            for(Account account2 : accountList2){       

            System.assertEquals('Without Oppty', account2.Last_Opportunity_ID__c); 
            } 
}

}
```

Thank you!